# What's significant in Abel's Theorem Proof in Baby Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

Refering to Theorem 8.2 in Baby Rudin

> **8.2 Theorem**  Suppse $\sum c_n$ converges. Put
>   $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n   \ \ \ \ (-1<x<1)$$
>   Then
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$$

The proof in Rudin is that outlined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)

However, Factoring out $(1-x)$ seems not natural for me.

The theorem looks like a extension from Theorem 8.1.

Indeed, by imitating the proof of Rudin 7.11
$$|f(t)-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_n|\leq|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n-\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_n|+|\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_n-\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_nt^n|+|\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_nt^n-f(t)|$$
where $t \in(-1,1)$

1.The first term can be arbitrary small for large N since $\sum c_n$ converges.

2.The second term can be small when $t\rightarrow1$ since polynomial is continuous.

3.Since f(x) is uniform convergent on $(-1,1)$, the third term can also be arbitrary small.

Then, I can also conclude the same result as in Theorem 8.2.

Could anyone kindly explain why Rudin uses a different approach (like factoring out (1-x)) or my reasoning has flaws, if there is any ?

**Summary of the discussion** :

The problem in my proof arises from  the third term in the inequality, where I mistake the order to take limits 
(I implicitly make $t \rightarrow 1$ and then $ N \rightarrow \infty$. This is wrong).

The motivation (I guess) in Rudin's proof is from Rudin **Theorem 3.42**, where we study the criteria to test conditional convergent series. **Theorem 8.2** has a similar situation, the sum $\sum c_n$ may very well be not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Why is it uniform on (-1,1)? I think it is only uniform on closed subsets of (-1,1)

Comment: Yes. But [-1+$\epsilon$,1-$\epsilon$] for any $\epsilon>0$ is just (-1,1).

Comment: $x^n$ converges locally uniformly to 0 on (0,1) but not uniformly

Comment: @CalvinKhor Excuse me, what does this imply? I have no exposure to the term ''locally uniform''.

Comment: locally uniform is what i said above: uniform on closed and bounded subsets

Comment: "Siganficient"?

Comment: In 2., what is $x $?

Comment: Ok, why don't you write as 2.5 a proof that $f$ is uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$? If you manage to do that correctly, then yes, you have a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim that
$$\left | \sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n - f(x) \right| \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0 \quad \text{uniformly in  }(-1,1) $$
this is not necessarily true. For it to have any chance to be true, it
must make reference to the extra assumption that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n$ exists, because its not true for arbitrary power series that converge (locally uniformly) on $(-1,1)$.

For instance, consider $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x}$. Its partial sums cannot converge uniformly on any $(1-\epsilon,1)$ since the partial sums are bounded  but the limit is unbounded.

Comment: Sorry if I miss something. Isn't "the $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n$ exists" in the hypothesis of the theorem?

Comment: @MathTheNovice but you use the statement i quoted above as a black box, and its not true.

Comment: So basically, if $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} c_n $ exists, apply M-test and my statement can be proven true. Yes?

Comment: @Math No. The $c_n $ don't need to be positive.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I mean the statement 3. $\sum c_n$ exists, f(x) radius of convergence is at least 1, and thus the f(x) is absolutely convergent in (-1,1). Apply M-test, now uniform convergence of f(x) in (-1,1) follows.

Comment: @MathTheNovice Andres is pointing out that the M test assumptions have $M_n \ge 0$

Comment: I see. However, If f(x) is absolutely convergent in (-1,1), I can apply M-test since M>0 and now series f(x) is uniform convergent in (-1,1). Is this correct?

Comment: @Math No. $f (x) $ is absolutely convergent in the interior of its interval of convergence. This does not make the $c_n $ be positive, so the M-test may not apply. But yes, if you know to begin with that $\sum c_n $ converges absolutely, then you can proceed as you suggest. But this case is significantly easier than the general case, where $\sum c_n $ only converges conditionally.